# Mostrar produtos por parâmetro de categoria de uma maneira mais otimizada

Tags: php, sql

Boa noite! Bom, explicarei o que estou tentando fazer. Tenho aqui uma *table* no meu banco de dados que corresponde aos produtos e tenho uma página que mostra esses produtos. Acontece que um dos parâmetros dessa *table* diz respeito à categoria de determinado produto. O que eu preciso é mostrar os produtos por categoria me utilizando desse parâmetro. Cada categoria deve ter um *HTML Heading* informando o nome da categoria antes de inserir abaixo os produtos referentes a ela. O detalhe é que eu já consegui fazer isso, mas de uma maneira meio "suja". Eu estou usando uma variável para setar o nome de determinada categoria e depois estou estabelecendo uma conexão com o banco de dados que compara o valor da variável com o valor da categoria de cada produto, e então insere-os abaixo do *HTML Heading* correspondente àquela categoria. O ruim disso é que eu tenho que criar manualmente várias conexões de acordo com o número de categorias presentes, e eu acho que existe uma maneira melhor de se fazer isso.
Creio que tudo ficará mais claro com o código.

```
$categoria_produto = "Comidas";

$sql = "SELECT id_produto, nome_produto, preco_produto, categoria_produto FROM produtos WHERE categoria_produto LIKE '{$categoria_produto}' ORDER BY nome_produto";
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0)
{
    echo "<h1>{$categoria_produto}</h1>";
        echo "<table>";
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "      <th>NOME</th>";
        echo "      <th>PREÇO</th>";
        echo "      <th>QUANTIDADE</th>";
        echo "  </tr>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        $preco_produto_reajustado = number_format($preco_produto, 2, ",", ".");
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "      <td><div class='id-produto' style='display: none'>{$id_produto}</div>";
        echo "      <div class='nome-produto'>{$nome_produto}</div></td>";
        echo "      <td>R&#36;{$preco_produto_reajustado}</td>";
        echo "      <td>";
        echo "          <form class='adicionar'>";
        echo "          <input type='number' name='quantidade' value='1' min='1' max='20'/>";
        echo "          <button type='submit'>Adicionar</button>";
        echo "          </form>";
        echo "      </td>";
        echo "  </tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "Sem produtos na categoria {$categoria_produto}.<br/>";
}
```

Vejam por que não estou gostando deste método. Todo esse código acima diz respeito apenas à categoria `Comidas`! Por exemplo, se eu quiser que os produtos referentes à categoria `Eletrônicos` sejam mostrados também, terei que usar logo abaixo:

```
$categoria_produto = "Eletrônicos";

$sql = "SELECT id_produto, nome_produto, preco_produto, categoria_produto FROM produtos WHERE categoria_produto LIKE '{$categoria_produto}' ORDER BY nome_produto";
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if($num>0)
{
    echo "<h1>{$categoria_produto}</h1>";
        echo "<table>";
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "      <th>NOME</th>";
        echo "      <th>PREÇO</th>";
        echo "      <th>QUANTIDADE</th>";
        echo "  </tr>";
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        $preco_produto_reajustado = number_format($preco_produto, 2, ",", ".");
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "      <td><div class='id-produto' style='display: none'>{$id_produto}</div>";
        echo "      <div class='nome-produto'>{$nome_produto}</div></td>";
        echo "      <td>R&#36;{$preco_produto_reajustado}</td>";
        echo "      <td>";
        echo "          <form class='adicionar'>";
        echo "          <input type='number' name='quantidade' value='1' min='1' max='20'/>";
        echo "          <button type='submit'>Adicionar</button>";
        echo "          </form>";
        echo "      </td>";
        echo "  </tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "Sem produtos na categoria {$categoria_produto}.<br/>";
}
```

O *output* está sendo o desejado, mas o código não está me agradando.
[image: O *output* está sendo o desejado, mas o código não está me agradando.]
Como eu disse anteriormente, não estou achando viável solucionar esse problema desta forma, creio que existe uma maneira melhor de se fazer o que estou pretendendo. Desde já agradeço por qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como cada um tem o seu jeito de programar, vamos dar ênfase a sua consulta, a forma que considero mais correta seria criar uma tabela `categoria` e então criar uma `foreing key` na tabela de `produto`, ficando:

```
[PRODUTO]
id_produto
nome_produto
preco_produto
id_categoria

[CATEGORIA]
id_categoria
descricao
```

Dessa forma, você faria uma consulta assim:

```
SELECT 
  p.id_produto,
  p.nome_produto,
  p.preco_produto,
  p.id_categoria,
  c.descricao 
FROM
  produtos p, categoria c 
WHERE c.id_categoria = p.id_categoria 
ORDER BY p.id_categoria,
  p.nome_produto
```

Até aqui organizamos sua estrutura para que otimize a busca e o armazenamento dos dados, assim não precisa gravar inúmeras vezes o nome de uma categoria, mas sim, relacionar o produto com o id correspondente.

Agora vamos ao código, ao invés de fazer vários selects por categoria, faça uma consulta só organizando primeiro pela categoria e depois pelo nome do produto, imprimindo tudo no mesmo laço, ficando assim:

```
//Editado devido a um pequeno erro de sintaxe
$sql = "SELECT p.id_produto, p.nome_produto, p.preco_produto, p.id_categoria, c.descricao FROM produtos p, categoria c WHERE c.id_categoria = p.id_categoria ORDER BY p.id_categoria, p.nome_produto";
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();
$categoria = null;
if($num>0) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        extract($row);
        if($categoria != $id_categoria) {
            if(!is_null($categoria)) { echo "</table>"; } // Fechando a tabela da ultima categoria impressa antes de abrir a nova

            echo "<h1>{$descricao}</h1>";
            echo "<table>";
            echo "  <tr>";
            echo "      <th>NOME</th>";
            echo "      <th>PREÇO</th>";
            echo "      <th>QUANTIDADE</th>";
            echo "  </tr>";

            $categoria = $id_categoria;
        }

        $preco_produto_reajustado = number_format($preco_produto, 2, ",", ".");
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "      <td><div class='id-produto' style='display: none'>{$id_produto}</div>";
        echo "      <div class='nome-produto'>{$nome_produto}</div></td>";
        echo "      <td>R&#36;{$preco_produto_reajustado}</td>";
        echo "      <td>";
        echo "          <form class='adicionar'>";
        echo "          <input type='number' name='quantidade' value='1' min='1' max='20'/>";
        echo "          <button type='submit'>Adicionar</button>";
        echo "          </form>";
        echo "      </td>";
        echo "  </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>"; // Fechando a tabela da última categoria do laço

}
```

Se não quiser mudar a estrutura do seu banco como a sugerida, pode fazer o mesmo laço, porem, tratando a descrição da categoria ao invés do id como fiz.

Claro que existem diversas formas, essa é uma delas, espero que ajude.

Abraço

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Nunca tinha trabalhado com `Foreign Key` mas vi que é bem prático e adaptei ao meu código seguindo a sua lógica! Só uma rápida correção na sua resposta, faltou uma vírgula depois do `FROM` entre `produtos p categoria c` para separar as tabelas, ficando assim `produtos p, categoria c`. Após essa pequena correção tudo funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela assistência e por ter tomado de seu tempo para me ajudar a otimizar o meu código! Grande abraço!

Comment: Bem observado @M.Victor, leia mais sobre relacionamento entre tabelas em http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql/

Disponha
Abraços